# Beautiful Soup - ignore `<span>` while providing `string` to `find()` method

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am parsing some text in Python, using BeautifulSoup4.

The address block starts with a cell like this:

```
<td><strong>Address</strong></td>
```

I find the above cell using `soup.find("td", "Address")`

But, now some addresses have a highlight character too, like this:

```
<td><strong><span>*</span>Address</strong></td>
```

This has broken my matching.  Is there still a way to find this TR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a solution like this:

```
    strong_blocks = soup.find_all("strong")
    def common_block(tag):
        return tag.find(string="Address", recursive=False)
    address_texts = list(filter(common_block, strong_blocks))
    if len(address_texts) == 1:
        address_text = address_texts[0]
        address_cell = address_text.parent
```

The *trick* was that once I had a list of `<strong>` elements, I was able to use `recursive=False` to prevent the `<span>` being inspected.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using either `CSS selector or re` as follows:

```
soup.select('td:has(strong:contains("Address"))')
```

OR

```
import re
soup.find("td", text=re.compile("Address"))
```